# Sharing webpage elements over a Reverse proxy across two servers

Tags: php, apache, curl, reverse-proxy

I have an ecommerce system and a blog both working independently on two servers. The ecommerce server reverse proxies the blog

/blog

This is all working fine, however my question is what is the best way to attain the header webpage element from one server to the other, taking into consideration there are dynamic elements within the header, basket count and user name if logged in.

The only solution I came up with is to grab the header via curl or the likes and cache periodically. Then enhance it with session data which is shared across the servers, i.e. the basket count, username.

Thanks in advance, hope this makes sense

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a single server to reverse proxy, you can perform ajax requests to this single site without worrying about any of the cross-site policy shenanigans.

Lets say you have the following

> /blog -> Your blog server
>   /notblog -> Your EC server.

From a page served from under `/blog` you can fetch a url like `/notblog/basket.php` with an ajax request, and update various parts of your header with the relevant information.

Alternatively (a far more crude solution) would be to include `/notblog/basket.php` as a script file, and dynamically generate javascript that simply prints your header contents. (remember to add headers to prevent it from caching!)

Both of these require an extra request to your site, but so would your proposed solution of using cURL.

Comment: Cheers for your response. I did consider this route, however with the curl request I would also be caching the response periodically so the additional request would only trigger when the resource was stale.

Comment: "*There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things*"

Comment: I'm using a hybrid of both our methods. Curl to return the basic header structure and caching the response. Then "enhancing" the header with data returned from an ajax request to a script held on the ecommerce server basket count, user name etc. As the ajax request originates from the clients machine, so this can invoke the session, userid etc. to make it all possible. Thanks for your help Leigh!